# Glassfish Security Realms and Rewrite rules with PrettyFaces

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, url-rewriting, glassfish, prettyfaces

I have problem with secure a page of my application. Here is my PrettyFaces rewrite rule:

```
<url-mapping id="cms"> 
      <pattern value="/administrator" /> 
      <view-id value="/faces/backend/index.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

and here is my secure configuration in web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Admin Pages</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Admin Area</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/faces/backend/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>JDBCRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/faces/login/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/faces/login/loginerror.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

As you can see I would like to secure all views under:

```
 /faces/backend/*
```

but problem is that. When i go to url (rewrite) like:

```
 http://mydomain/administrator
```

Application should redirect to login page beacuse this url lead to secured view under /faces/backend/*. But user can enter on this page.

When i use url like:

```
 http://mydomain/faces/backend/index.xhtml
```

Secure work correct. But i would like to secure rewrite rule too. How to fix it? I will greatful for help.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to protect resources this way:

1. All .xhtml resources placed to `/WEB-INF/views` (they become not accessible by direct link)
2. All my sequrity settings use rewrited URLs

> ```
> <web-resource-collection>  
>   <web-resource-name>protected-pages</web-resource-name>  
>   <url-pattern>/administration/*</url-pattern>  
>   <url-pattern>/moderation/*</url-pattern>
> </web-resource-collection>
> ```

Or you can use multiple url-patterns to protect your resources (but it is not best solution)

> ```
>   <url-pattern>/faces/backend/*</url-pattern>
>   <url-pattern>/administrator</url-pattern>
> ```